# Formula field's actual formula

Tags: formula-field

IS there any way to get what a configured formula fields actual formula is?

Strange ask, I know, but we dont use visual force for our front end. We build it ourselves with JS. The issue then is obviously that formula fields do not update until we save. Just wondering if there is any way to get the formula, as a string or anything else, that I could pass from Apex to our front end?

Comment: You can get the formula via metadata API access, which is a REST service. I know you said you don't use VF, but rather use JS. However, is it that your front-end is actually a VF page with lots of imported scripts etc.? Are you using VFRemoting to access the data from Salesforce? Or are you not using Salesforce UI technology at all (and managing authentication, authorization and server-side access all yourselves)? If you use VF page and VFRemoting you can get the back-end to update formula fields through SObject.recalculateFormulas without save through a controller function/property.

Comment: Its all pure JS, so there is no Salesforce UI at all

Comment: What Salesforce API is the JS using? How are you performing authentication and authorization?